# Select and trigger click of hidden element based on it's css value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some div's [up to 1000] whose class name are same and different colours .
         please see the following html

```
     <div class="class-1" style="background-color:red; display:none;">1</div>
     <div class="class-1" style="background-color:black; display:none;">2</div>
     <div class="class-1" style="background-color:rgb(0,12,34); display:none;">3</div>
     ...
     <div class="class-1" style="background-color:rgb(5,12,65); display:none;">1000</div>
```

**Here  how can i trigger the click of class1 whose background color is black** ? I check with filter function but  i didn't get the correct result

```
 $(".class-1").filter(function(){
       var match="black";
   return ( $(".class-1").css('background-color') == match );
}).trigger("click");
```

Please help.

Comment: Oh man this does not seem like a good way to do this, if possible you should assign the styles to different classes and query using $("className").click(function(){}); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the below. It should work

```
 var match = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
```

Here is CodePen: http://codepen.io/rachitgulati26/pen/MJjaBp.

Comment: Could you please attach the code here , instead of writting in codepen . Thank you .

Comment: also, how can i add extra class to the selected one ? for example i need to add a class named selected to the one who have background color is black

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to write a closing quote on your code on the second line.

Try changing it to `var match="black";` and see if that helps.

The jQuery function `.css()` works that way and should work.

See https://api.jquery.com/css/ for more information, but based on the first example they give it is possible to retrieve your colour string that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use data tags.
HTML

```
<div data-color="black">black</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('[data-color="black"]').html('black found');
```

Comment: sorry , i cannot rewrite the html structure .